# Calling an inner function?

Tags: scala

I am trying to call an inner function as so...

```
scala> def myouter() = {
     |   def myInner() {
     |     println("In inner now")
     |   }
     |   this
     | }
myouter: ()type

scala> myouter().myInner()
    <console>:9: error: value myInner is not a member of object $iw
          myouter().myInner()
                    ^
```

Any tips on how I achieve this?

Comment: A method is not a class/type, it does not contain members... myInner is just an other method in the scope of the myouter method... I recommend you read this free book: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Inner functions are private to the scope in which they are declared.

Comment: C. Sobrai can I not return the inner function?

Comment: @dublintech - You can return the inner _function_ but that is after it is converted to a function.  The method itself remains private.

Comment: @Rex Kerr - any chance of a snippet?

Comment: @dublintech Return `myInner _` instead of `this`, for example.